# unreadable format of user first name in django

Tags: python, django

I have an article model with author field that the user can't submit through a form because it is his first name and last name, I put only first_name so if you can help me put last_name I will be grateful:

```
author = models.CharField('author',max_length=50, default=User.first_name)
```

When saved to the database it shows that author is `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x111874dc0>`
Because I can't import account, which is also a model I use User.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your problem clearly. With my understanding, if you want to automatically update the author field when a user submits an article, I recommend you to do the update in `views.py`.

**models.py**

```
author = models.CharField('author', max_length=50, default=None)
```

**views.py**

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
author_name = user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name      # any format
article = Article(author=author_name)
article.save()
```

The other fields required for `Article()` are omitted here. You may want to get them from `POST` method yourself.

Comment: But I am submitting it through a form and using account model.

Comment: I think you are talking about ManyToOneRelation. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446168/14059614) might already answer your question. And if you want to include the last name as well, please refer to the format above. Note that you can `save()` multiple times/models inside a function if you are not using ManyToOneRelation.