# Save user first_name as default value for model django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have an article model with author variable which I want to save as the users first and last name. I use custom user model called Account.

```
author = models.CharField('author',max_length=50 default=User.first_name)
```

When saved  it shows the author is `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10b461dc0>` So how can I retrieve the account first name when saving this form:

```
form = ArticleCreationForm(request.POST) 
        # check if form data is valid 
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid(): 
                form.save() 
            # save the form data to model 
    
        context['form']= form
```

forms.py:

```
class ArticleCreationForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    # specify the name of model to use 
    class Meta: 
        model = Article 
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ['votes', 'author']
```

It would be good if you can make it so that the user sees the author field with his name but can't edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide some default value like this in CharField.

```
author = models.CharField('author',max_length=50, default='First Name')
```

You can save the user(current user) first name in your author field like this while saving the form.

```
if request.method == "POST":      
    form = ArticleCreationForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid(): 
        article = form.save(commit=False) 
        article.author = request.user.first_name # the user must be logged in for this.
        article.save()
        return redirect('some_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  use the below mentioned codes for generating the author model and use it corresponding to the post they create :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and you can call this user/author where u need in your model using :

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```